# Share the same parameter from model in the toplevel with all components in dymola

Tags: simulation, modelica, dymola

i tried to use something like this:

Toplevel with Model1 and the Model with the Parameter in it.

Parametermodel:
Parameter heat_coeffi = 50;

Model1:
outer [Path:Parametermodel] name;
Parameter heat_coeffi = name.heatcoeffi;

The Error message is : "Found non-inner parametermodel for inner model
Failed to find matching inner ....

I tried to use it just like they use System from the original Modelica Lib.

Comment: With this description it is a bit difficult to help. If you could post a simple example that would help a lot.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that you probably did not make the instance of the "Parametermodel" an inner model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you *instantiate* the `Parametermodel` (similar to the `Modelica.Fluid.System`) in the top-level model. When you do so you must instantiate it as an `inner` model. In that way the other instantiated models (`model1` etc.) know where to find the global parameters.

In `Modelica.Fluid.System` there is an annotation `defaultComponentPrefixes="inner"` that ensures that it is automatically instantiated as an inner model.

Comment: i am pretty sure this should fix it, but for now its giving me the same errors. Trying out some stuff now.